# How do I broadcast a value across multiple cells in Excel?

Tags: excel-formula

I am creating a rent allocation sheet for multiple facilities paid from multiple contracts. I have added my formulas to calculate monthly payments to facilities from different contracts. I also utilized the TODAY() function to create a moving month header based on the current date. I want to broadcast the value (monthly payment that doesn't change) across multiple months based on the remaining amount of months (from column F). 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZByLS.png)

Comment: What do you do in April? Use a new sheet or delete the column?

Comment: Or do you mean the month header is the column heads that change? What happens then to the value in months remaining? If the columns remain fixed you could use sth like `=IF(1<B1;C1;"")` with 1 in this case being the value in column APRIL, 2 in MAY, etc, B referencing the column MONTHS REMAINING, C MARCH.

Comment: The monthly column automatically adjusts to the current month. Basically on a 12 month cycle with the current month being the first month. This will automatically change the months remaining on contract (F column). I want to use the months remaining to determine how many times the payment is broadcast out.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Like this? (WENN is IF in german)